# Check if important Windows Update is available

Tags: command-line, windows-update

When deploying any application, it could be needed, that user has computer updated to latest OS version of Windows. Windows XP/Win7/Win8.

[image: Windows 8 update - German]
*in this example, one important update is available on a Windows 8 system.*

.

[image: Update Windows 7]
*in this example, 15 important updates are available on Windows 7 system.*

.

How to get information if **any** important Windows update is available on this computer?

I found a way how to get a specific KB patch:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799414/windows-update-agents-vs-wmic-qfe-get/12802736#12802736

But I don't have a list of each OS system and each KB and just want to know if any update is available. If no internet connection is available, don't care about it.

I also found [Windows Update API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387099%28VS.85%29.aspx) but could not imagine how that should solve my situation.

**How to find out if more than zero important (not optional) updates are available?**